# Normalize response variable?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization

I understand one should normalize the features in supervised learning.

Does it ever make sense to normalize the response variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of normalization is to prevent a subset of features from dominating the behavior of the model.  So normalizing the output variable is not critical.

Perhaps if you're implementing the model using low-precision or fixed point math. For example, in an MCU for an embedded system.  On a server, desktop or laptop using floats or doubles it's not critical to normalize the output.